# Consultar una base de datos en un chunck dentro de un NoteBook

Tags: r

Hola estoy intentando consultar una base de datos SQl Express con el método de usar el propio chunk para no tener que formatear la SQL y esto me marca errores que no entiendo

````
```{r,sql, connection=con,output.var="df2"}
select 
    Empleados.firstName + ' ' + Empleados.middleName + ' ' + Empleados.lastName as Jefe_Proyecto,
    Planificadores.U_refproy as Proyecto, 
    Planificadores.U_reffase as Fase
from [@ITAPROYSEG] Planificadores 
inner join OPRJ proyectos on Planificadores.U_refproy=Proyectos.PrjCode
inner join  OHEM Empleados on Planificadores.U_empid=Empleados.empID
inner join [@ITAPROYFASES] Fases on Planificadores.U_reffase=Fases.U_codfase
where Empleados.U_Activo='Sí' and Proyectos.U_prop1='Y'
order by Jefe_Proyecto, Proyecto, Fase
```
````

[image: error sql]

Alguna idea por favor?

Un saludo

Comment: Parece que tienes un error tipográfico en la definición del chunk, no es `{r,sql, connection=con,output.var="df2"}`, sino `{sql, connection=con,output.var="df2"}`, es decir solo `sql`

Comment: Si lo pongo sí me desaparecen las opciones del chunck es decir no tengo el boton para ejecutarlo

Comment: Los chunks solo tiene  un lenguaje posible, así como lo tienes interpreta que es código R y obviamente no lo es. Debes dejar solo `{sql, ....}`, eso  es así, que no te lo reconozca como un chunk ejecutable es en realidad el problema. Revisa la versión de knitr con `packageVersion("knitr")` el soporte para SQL recién lo pusieron en la versión 1.4

Comment: Yo tengo la versión 1.28 pero cuando intento actualizarlo me dice que todos os paquetes están ya actualizados

Comment: Se me escapó un dedo, quise poner versión 1.14, la 1.28 esta perfecta por que es la última. Lamentablemente no se me ocurre mucho más, lo he reproducido en mi equipo y funciona de maravillas.